# Using %d to keep double format when appending to new StringBuilder output

Tags: java, arrays, printf, stringbuilder

I'm not sure it's even worth it to go to this length. I'm just tinkering around to figure things out. Honestly it seems useless what I'm doing but I might not know of a purpose for what I'm trying to accomplish, if there even is one.

I learned that when using printf, you can format the arguments to remain as int instead of being converted to string.

The example provided was:

```
System.out.printf("Testing %d" , 1);
```

So I got to thinking. What if I could keep the values of an array as a double when I append it to a new StringBuilder object? Is that possible? In the event I wanted to (For whatever ridiculous reason) say modify the values of what is printed by taking those values directly from within the appended object.

Is this retarded? Seriously.

```
public  static String[] brands = { "PA", "PB", "PC" , "PD", "PE"};
public  static double[] price = { 14.20, 13.75, 21.55, 38, 1};

private static StringBuilder sarray = new StringBuilder();

for (place = 0; place < brands.length; place++) {
        sarray.append(brands[place] + " $"+ price[place] * cansneeded + "\n");
    }
    System.out.printf(sarray.toString());
```

In this scenario, I want to keep the element values of price as a double using %d once they're inside of the sarray for even further manipulation. the brands array is a String array. Anyone got any tips on where to look to accomplish this? Is this possible? Am I on the wrong track with this one and there's new tools I haven't learned yet to accomplish this task?

Comment: `%d` is formatting `int`. It seems like you want `%.2f` which formats floating point numbers to two decimal places. Using `double` is not great for storing prices (it does not have arbitrary precision). `String.format("$%.2f", 3.33)` for example.

Comment: This is what I came up with:

`sarray.append(String.format(brands[place] + " " + "$%.2f\n" ,price[place] * cansneeded));`

It worked. Thank you for the info about float. I converted it all.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use `printf` (or, `format`) once you've already created a string, as you do in your last line. Just use `System.out.print(sarray);` at that point. Also, you should not use `double` for monetary values. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: So after the formatting is completed using String.format, the data would remain the same inside sarray. Or did you mean omit String.format? I'd merely be printing the result. Doing printf would be redundant. I'll check info BigDecimal tomorrow. I changed a lot of this code today as I went along learning new things. Thanks for the follow up.